# I just lost both wired and wifi network (Ubuntu14.04)

Tags: networking, internet

Something terrible has happend to my Ubuntu 14.04 installation. I can't get no wired or wifi internet connection. The computer connects to my wifi-network but I can't access the internet. I can  `ping 8.8.8.8` and `192.168.1.1`.

When executing `nmcli nm` I get

```
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         connected       enabled         enabled    enabled         disabled
```

and when executing "route", the output is:

Kernel IP routing table

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

The router is working since other Machines can connect to the router

Any suggestions ? Please help !

Comment: What does ifconfig -a say?

Comment: wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          inet addr:192.168.1.71  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::762f:68ff:fec7:6213/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1094 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1044 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:93579 (93.5 KB)  TX bytes:113071 (113.0 KB)

Comment: Do you have a firewall enabled on your Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can `ping` by ip address, you probably have a DNS issue.

What you can attempt is setting custom DNS server on your Ubuntu machine. My preferred method is adding `supersede domain-name-servers xx.xx.xx.xx` in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file.

For instance, this is excerpt from my `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. Line numbers added for ease of finding where to place that line:

```
    16  #send host-name "andare.fugue.com";
    17  send host-name = gethostname();
    18  #send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
    19  #send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
    20  #supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
    21  supersede domain-name-servers 208.67.220.220;
    22  #prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
    23  request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    24      domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    25      dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
    26      netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    27      rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
    28      dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
    29  #require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
```

What does it do ? Basically, when you connect to a router, the machine asks DHCP server on the router to provide it with specific settings, among which is DNS server address. `supersede domain-name-server` basically means, give me everything else, but replace whatever the router has given me with my own DNS server. In the example above I use openDNS. With that setting, openDSN will be my domain name-server no matter to which network I connect

Once you have edited the file, restart `network-manager` with `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: I tried adding "supersede domain-name-servers 208.67.220.220;" No difference. I might also add that Dropbox is not able to connect to server which might indicate that it is not a nameserver problem ?

Comment: @Magnus OK, now reconnect to the network. You can  do `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: Tried restarting the computer as well as restarting the network via sudo service network-manager restart. No difference ...

Comment: I added 208.67.222.222 in /etc/resolve.conf and now the network  works ! Thanks for helping me out !

Comment: @Magnus Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved, but it may come back, as `/etc/resolv.conf` gets overwritten every time you connect to different network. I suggest you add the address to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` file to keep it permanent